# Can I word wrap a URL inside a HTML hyperlink

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, word-wrap, removing-whitespace

Is there a way to separate the URL name in a hyperlink so it continues onto the next line?  In the application I am using I need to use a long URL and the space is limited so it wraps around to the next line.  However, a space is automatically added to it and the link is then broken.  Is there a continuation character to tell the application to keep link together or a way to use a shorter variable name that contains the longer actual URL?

Comment: I recommend that you just use different software.
If it is the application that has a CPL (character per line) limit, it isn't the
best software for coding. I would personally recommend [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) Edit: or use can use a URL shortener like [Bit.ly](https://bitly.com)
or [TinyURL](http://tinyurl.com)

Answer (score 0):

No, HTML treats any and all whitespace characters (including multiple series of them) as a single space. You cannot disable this.

Answer (score 0):

Is it absolutely necessary to put the URL as the hyperlink text?

In fact, showing a shorter meaningful description about the URL would be better for the hyperlink text.

meaning descr

I don't the actual requirement, but thought to leave this comment for you.

Comment: It is actually the href resource name that is too long, not the text name. The blahbalh......... is too long and it wraps around to the next line then breaks the link because a space is put in the link. The application only allows you to enter the html code in a small rectangular box.

Comment: The blahblah in the comment is the url reference name.